# NGINX response with 404 on static resourse of SwaggerUI - (Express)

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, swagger

swaggerUI works on my localhost but when I try to integrate it with nginx it doesn't work.

When you try to get the static swagger files the server doesn't find them. It may be that the reverse proxy doesn't work. Any ideas?

These are the configuration files and log files:

**error.log of nginx***

```
2020/01/29 13:47:54 [error] 933#933: *2432 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/documentation/swagger-ui.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 190.190.190.28, server: mywebsite.com.com, request: "GET /documentation/swagger-ui.css HTTP/2.0", host: "mywebsite.com", referrer: "https://mywebsite.com/documentation/"
2020/01/29 13:47:54 [error] 933#933: *2432 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/documentation/swagger-ui-bundle.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 190.190.190.28, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET /documentation/swagger-ui-bundle.js HTTP/2.0", host: "mywebsite.com", referrer: mywebsite.com/documentation/"
2020/01/29 13:47:54 [error] 933#933: *2432 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/documentation/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 190.190.190.28, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET /documentation/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js HTTP/2.0", host: "mywebsite.com", referrer: "https://mywebsite.com/documentation/"
```

**site.conf [nginx]**

```
# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/css                   1y;
    application/javascript     1y;
    ~image/                    1M;
}

server {
    server_name mywebsite.com;

    expires $expires;

    index index.html;

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    sendfile on;

    location ~ \.css
    {
      add_header Content-Type text/css;
    }

    location ~ \.js
    {
      add_header Content-Type application/javascript;
    }

    location /
    {
      expires -1;
      add_header Pragma "no-cache";
      add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
      #root /var/www;
      try_files $uri $uri/;
      return 301 https://mywebsite.com/documentation;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$
    {
      expires -1;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$
    {
      expires 1M;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$
    {
      expires 1d;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000/api/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1; # this is essential for chunked responses to work
      proxy_buffering    off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      # set client body size to 200M #
      client_max_body_size 200M;
    }


    location /documentation/ {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000/documentation/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1; # this is essential for chunked responses to work
      proxy_buffering    off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      client_max_body_size 200M;
    }

   .... ####  Certbot conf #### ....

}
```

**swaggerDoc.js (express)**

```
'use strict'
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true })
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express')
const swaggerJSDoc = require('swagger-jsdoc')
const config = require('./conf')
const DisableTryItOutPlugin = function() {
  return {
    statePlugins: {
      spec: {
        wrapSelectors: {
          allowTryItOutFor: () => () => false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Swagger definition
const swaggerDefinition = {
  openapi: "3.0.0",
  info: {
    title: "*****",
    version: "1.0.0",
    description:
      "Api Rest",
    termsOfService: 'http://example.com',
    license: {
      name: "MIT license",
      url: "https://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/"
    },
    contact: {
      name: "*****",
      email: "*****"
    }
  },
  host: `${config.api.apiUrl}`,
  servers: [
    {
      url: `${config.api.apiUrl}`
    }
  ]
}

// options for the swagger docs
const options = {
  swaggerDefinition,
  apis: ['./**/routes/*.js'],
};

// options for the swagger UI
const optionsUI = {
  swaggerOptions: {
      plugins: [
           DisableTryItOutPlugin,
      ],
   }
};

// initialize swagger-jsdoc
const swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(options)

module.exports = () => {
  //app.use('/documentation', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec,{ explorer: true }))
  router.use("/documentation", swaggerUi.serve);
  router.get(
    "/documentation",
    swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec,optionsUI)
  )
  return router
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `root` of your location blocks. It causes nginx to fail when serving your static files. If your static assets are stored under the same path, you can move the `root` in the server block as follows:

```
server {
    server_name mywebsite.com;

    expires $expires;

    index index.html;

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    root /api/static;    # change this to your path

    # the rest of your configuration
}
```

Comment: The problem is  those files are dynamically generated by swagger, they aren't in a specific directory :(

Comment: @otta for sake of testing, would you try commenting this block in your config? 
` location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ { ...  } `

Also, the files are generated dynamically, but the path doesn't change; nginx tries to get the assets from the default folder `/usr/share/nginx/html/`, is this the base path of your documentation?

You can even specify the swagger output path with the `-output` flag when calling the `swagger-codegen` command.

Comment: I commented the lines you said and still not working. I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-express/v/4.1.3 for documentation. The static files are in the node_modules/swagger-ui-dist folder, I think it wouldn't make sense to point the root directory to that folder... The swagger-ui-express library doesn't generate static documentation :(

Answer (score 0):

Just for workaround, **do this only if you know what's going on**:

remove `expire 1d;` in

```
location ~* \.(?:css|js)$
    {
      expires 1d;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
```

then restart nginx, everything should works fine.